# What is the meaning of かい and き in Google's Summer Solstice Doodle?

Tags: colloquial-language, phrases

I was wondering what the meaning of かい and き is for the Google Summer Solstice Doodle pictured here:
[image]

I'm guessing it has some relation to summer, but what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is unlikely that these Japanese letters have anything to do with summer.

These are mascots of [Kaikai Kiki Co., Ltd.](http://english.kaikaikiki.co.jp/whatskaikaikiki/), a company run by [Takashi Murakami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takashi_Murakami), the artist who painted this Google Doodle.  Also note that the same mascots appear in the [Winter Solstice Doodle](http://www.google.co.za/webhp?hl=en), too.

Comment: Ooh, now that I look at it, it does have an Aoshima Chiho-esque cute/spooky feel to it.

Comment: [Kaikai Kiki's website](http://www.kaikaikiki.co.jp/whatskaikaikiki/activity/) says Kaikai Kiki is `恠恠奇奇（カイカイキキ） ... 「怪しく、しかし魅了される」という意味` ("strange yet fascinating").

Comment: That's really cool. I never thought trying to go to Google South Africa would give me a Winter Solstice doodle! :)

Comment: Aww... that's pretty disappointing! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

快気 probably.  "Good feeling".  Or maybe 怪奇 for "weird", i.e., those strange pig-rabbits.

Comment: After all, 怪奇 is pretty close, considering the origin of the company name.